# Как создать нижнее меню в Android

Tags: android

Интересует, в каком направлении двигаться чтобы реализовать выезжающее меню внизу экрана либо при нажатии кнопки action floating button, либо при прокрутке вниз как на изображении
[image: Требуемое меню]

Comment: в сторону [BottomNavigarionView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView)

Answer (score 1):

используйте Bottom Sheet, вот статьи

https://habr.com/ru/post/309200/

https://medium.com/android-bits/android-bottom-sheet-30284293f066

так же можете посмотреть библиотеки

https://github.com/michaelbel/BottomSheet

https://github.com/Flipboard/bottomsheet

https://github.com/michael-rapp/AndroidBottomSheet

Comment: Благодарю! Немного не то, чего бы хотелось.На просторах Интернета как-то видел реализацию данного функционала, но найти не удается.

Answer (score 1):

Лучше всего использовать view по возможности от гугла, а если у гугла нет, тогда стороне либы. Для этого есть специальная view - [BottomNavigationView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView)

пример:

```
        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navigation"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="64dp"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/navigation_color_selector"
            app:itemTextColor="@drawable/navigation_color_selector"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="labeled"
            app:menu="@menu/navigation_menu" />
```